# jQuery - Make input value a var

Tags: jquery, text, var

I want to put a var text = "hello"

Into an input value. I am not sure how to do this, and I would like to know to this, as I am not sure.

I thought It would of just been `$(input#text).text(text);`
but that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) not `text()`:

```
$("#text").val(text);
```

The **`val()`** is used when you want to read from or write to **text fields**.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the documentation of jQuery for `text`, you'll see that `text()` manipulates text nodes (or text node content). If you're setting a value on a textbox you should be using the `val()` function.

```
$("input#text")
    .val(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
var text = "hello"
$('#id').val(text);
  //where id is the id assigned to your text box
 //eg.
<input type='text' id='mytextbox' value=''/>
 //it should be then 
var text = "hello"
$('#mytextbox').val(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign value of a text box whose id is textbox in jQuery ,do the following :-

```
$("#textbox").val(text);
```

See [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)